# Toggle button to show/hide data from API

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have a meetup.com API on my website that pulls in descriptions of events. I would like to have this information hidden by a toggle button so that when you click on 'More Info' the description shows.

Here is my javascript for the toggle button:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
$ct = 1;
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $event) {
   echo '<strong> ' . $event['name'] . '</strong>' . '<br />';
   echo '<strong>Event link:  </strong><a href="' . $event['event_url'] .'" target="_blank">' .  $event['event_url']  . '</a><br />';
   echo '<strong>When: </strong>' . date('Y-m-d H:i', $event['time']/1000) . '<br />' ;
  // echo '<strong>More Info: </strong>' . $event['description'] . '<br />';
   echo '<strong><button>More Info</button></strong><infobox>' . $event['description'] . '</infobox><br />';

$ct = $ct+1;
```

This is what it looks like live: http://maddusability.com/icm505/meetups.php

As you can see, it is only allowing me to show/hide all event descriptions at once, not individually - even though I created a unique id for each event. Any ideas?

Comment: What id? Where is the id?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `this` keyword and DOM traversal to target the correct elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('strong').next('infobox').find("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

FYI: `<infobox>` seems like an invalid tag to me ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a very generic jQuery selection. **You are toggling all the P tags in the page**.

What you should be doing is wrap each item in a separate div with a specific css class. Update the php file so that it will generate the below markup

```
<div class="item">
  <strong>Event 1</strong>
  <button class="showMore">Show more</button>
   <div class="moreInfo">
    <p>Your more info description goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <strong>Event 2</strong>
  <button class="showMore">Show more</button>
  <div class="moreInfo">
    <p>Your more info about event 2 description goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in your script, look for the click event on the button with `showMore` css class and when it is clicked, use the `closest()` method to get the container div and then use `find` method to get to the div which has the content to be toggled.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".moreInfo").hide();  //Hide all show more initially

    $("button.showMore").click(function(){
        var _this=$(this);
        _this.closest(".item").find(".moreInfo").toggle();
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xuwabu/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is a working sample.